# Chrome custom tabs - setCloseButtonIcon() not changing icon

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to change icon for close button in Chrome custom tabs. But it is not changing.

Here's my code:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
builder.setCloseButtonIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back));
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Post the complete code for creating CustomTabsIntent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setCloseButtonIcon() method doesn't change default Close button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614584/setclosebuttonicon-method-doesnt-change-default-close-button)

Comment: @AnuragSingh I've edited my code now.

Comment: After the setCloseButtonIcon(). Are you using these lines exactly: CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));

Comment: @AnuragSingh Yes. I have those lines.

Comment: Is there any padding in the icon?

Comment: @AnuragSingh No padding.

Comment: Try using this icon or image as close button http://www.filedropper.com/back_3

Comment: @AnuragSingh That doesn't work. It shows the same 'X' icon.

Comment: I would ask for one more thing and that is to post comlete code for custom Tab from creation to launching. Thanks

Comment: Share the close image and customtab gradle version because the same piece of code is working in my project?

Comment: Custom tabs version is 25.2.0 and the back button image that I'm trying to use is [ic_arrow_back](https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_back) of 24dp.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I stumbled across this and recently had what I believe is the same problem, so I'll answer.

I believe the issue is that you are using a vector drawable, but your code expects a PNG. I ran into this issue when I used a debugging breakpoint to discover that the result of parsing the image file was `null`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55260049/967131) helped me. Here's the most relevant code section from that answer. It uses [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx).

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp)?.let {
    builder.setCloseButtonIcon(it.toBitmap())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.html#KEY_ICON), the close icon needs to be 24dp x 24dp. Something like this works:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M7.2,14.4m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0"/>
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M14.8,18m-2,0a2,2 0,1 1,4 0a2,2 0,1 1,-4 0"/>
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M15.2,8.8m-4.8,0a4.8,4.8 0,1 1,9.6 0a4.8,4.8 0,1 1,-9.6 0"/>
</vector>
```